# Python - Amazon AMI - PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec

Tags: python, fabric

I am running latest Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03.1, with python 2.6.8 from their repository.

I did the following:

```
pip install fabric
```

When I run the command `fab`, I always get the following. It works fine but would like to get rid of the error if possible:

> /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py:57: PowmInsecureWarning: Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.
> _warn("Not using mpz_powm_sec.  You should rebuild using libgmp >= 5 to avoid timing attack vulnerability.", PowmInsecureWarning)

From `pip list` I see the following:

```
boto (2.9.7)
botocore (0.8.2)
distribute (0.7.3)
Fabric (1.7.0)
paramiko (1.11.0)
setuptools (1.0)
```

Is the only way to fix this is compile python from source?